# Embed crosswalk runtime inside cordova apk

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk

I uploaded my application to google play store but when I download it and open it it shows an error message like the one attached.

[image: error message]

Is there a way to embed this runtime and skip installing it separatly? I tried looking at the documentation but from what I understooed I have to rite Java code to embed it which did not make sense to me.

Comment: what version of Android are you running in the screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by generating the app from Cordova CMD using --release command instead of android studio...